# Migrating C# code from Cassandra .5 to .6

Tags: c#, cassandra, thrift

I have some some simple code derived from an example that is meant to form a quick write to the Cassandra db, then loop back and read all current entries, everything worked fine. When .6 came out, i upgraded Cassandra and thrift, which threw errors in my code (www[dot]copypastecode[dot]com/26760/) - i was able to iron out the errors by converting the necessary types, however in the version that compiles now only seems to read one item back, im not sure if its not saving db changes or if its only reading back 1 entry. the "fixed" code is here: http://www.copypastecode.com/26752/. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, let me say that you should definitly use `TBufferedStream` instead of `TSocket` for the `TBinaryProtocol`, that will make a huge impact on your application performance.

For the Apache Thrift API documentation that `BATCH_INSERT` methods is deprecated, so it could have introduced a misleading bug on that operation that actually only insert the first column. Said so, why don't you try to use `BATCH_MUTATE` instead?

By the way, why are you trying to use Thrift directly? There are some nice c# clients for Cassandra that are actually performing really well. You can find the whole list at http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions.

I'm the author of one of them are is pretty much updated with Apache and its being used by some companies on production environment. Take a look at my homepage.